# Fill factor for nonclustered index on an EmailAddress column?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out what an ideal fill factor would be for a non-clusetered index of a column such as EmailAddress. If I have a Person table that is frequently added to, a fill-factor of 0 would result in heavy fragmentation of the index since each new person will have an essentially random value here. In my case, the data is written to and read from frequently, but we have almost no changes or deletions. Are there any guidelines for indexing these types of columns regarding fill factor?

Comment: Have you actually measured and validated the heavy fragmentation? Consider what the "average" length of an email address for your data is, and how many would roughly fit on an 8K page; Personally I would stick with 0/100; once a page split occurs each page will then have ~50% free space but before that happens you'll be forcing each page to be x% empty, and your ram x% empty too.

Comment: I've checked avg_fragmentation_in_percent and found it to be up to 99% in some cases, yes. Or are you saying that it doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: Personally if your data is on fast SSD storage (it is, presumably) then fragmentation matters far less than it used to; I prefer to utilise my expensive RAM and minimise IO, which tends to mean a high fill-factor when indexes are rebuilt. It's a divisive topic though and seems prone to opinion.

Comment: Additionally, for an index on email addresses, that no doubt share many common domain names, I'd consider page compression that would yield good savings and much more efficient IO/memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about page compression on this index. I got a bit better than 2:1 compression when enabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill Factor is irrelevant unless you rebuild the index.  An index with "random" insertion points will generate page splits and naturally maintain room on pages to accommodate new rows, as split pages end up 50% full.

If you *do* rebuild such an index (which there's often no reason to do), then consider using a fill factor so you don't remove all the free space on pages, which would lead to a flurry of page splits after rebuild, the end result of which will be similar to (but more expensive than) rebuilding with a fill factor.

Emprically, 60-75 is a reasonable choice.